# Using nested if statements in Python Parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, vbscript

The solution in VB for the base process is at [If/then VBScript/Python code equivalent to SQL IN ('x','y',z') expression in ArcGIS Field Calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/if-then-vb-script-code-or-python-equivalent-to-sqls-in-x-y-z-express) works great but I was trying to nest 'if' statements and can't.

So pre-logic code of

```
if [grid_code] = 1 then 
f2= 2
end if
if [grid_code] = 2 then
f2=3.5
end if
```

...etc. but this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried the second 'if' before the 'end if' and also tried 'elif' but these give script errors.

Also I am seeing a warning message about "The calculated value is invalid for the row with objectID=1" and when you click click 'yes' to continue it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For VB, something like this should work, I think:

Pre-logic script code:

```
Dim f2 As Double
If [grid_code] = 1 Then
  f2 = 2
ElseIf [grid_code] = 2 Then
  f2 = 3.5
End If
```

asp_code =

```
f2
```

In Python, I think it would be something like this (though I don't have ArcGIS 10 so I can't check):

Pre-logic script code:

```
def my_func(my_field):
    if my_field == 1:
        f2 = 2
    elif my_field == 2:
        f2 = 3.5
    return f2
```

asp_code =

```
my_func(!grid_code!)
```

The error message saying that the "calculated value is invalid" is a bit strange. Perhaps double-check that your `asp_code` field is of `float` or `double` data type (not `integer`), and that you have all of the options in the grid_code field covered by your if statements? Sorry if that's too obvious, but it's all I can think of at the moment. Good luck!

Comment: +1 great answers. I'd lean towards using the Python solution, since it has more of a future than VBA.

Comment: Thanks James - the python code was almost perfect. I had to include f2 in the asp_code = re_score(!VEGTYPE_NU!,f2) and f2=99
def re_score(my_field,f2): in the pre-logic ... anyway it Runs in less that a minute with 45 my_field values in a dataset with 31,000 polygons.

Answer (score 3):

For Python syntax, I would suggest that you would want something like this with nested if ... elif statements.  As for the [grid_code] does it need to be enclosed in brackets? or is it a field?  if it is a field, then I suspect that replacing [] with double quotes would do the trick

```
...you need a def (aka function call name passing a field name to the following
if [grid_code] == 1: 
  f2= 2
elif [grid_code] == 2:
  f2=3.5
return f2
```

Update...
Of course boolean slicing is far easier in the field calculator, a demo, just insert ! marks around the field names (Gridcode, in this example, so it would be !Gridcode! in the field calculator)

```
>>> Gridcode = 1
>>> [3.5, 2.0][Gridcode == 1]
2.0
```

Comment: sorry I should have added the first line is "dim f2"...in VB. Using python is fine as well. Basically 'grid_code' is a field in the table and the f2 values get placed in another field called 'asp_code'. Maybe what I missed is the 'return f2'. Will try and see...

Comment: also what do you mean by needing a def? is it just def (f2, grid_code) as the first line? I can't try this now as I am away from my main desktop. best,