# Making two functions and then combining them in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, network-analyst, vbscript

I am new in the VBScript world, so I am really confused with programming.
I need to do this expression in my evaluator in my Network Analyst.
Basically I am adding a "cost" that is my percentage of primary roads, where:

```
TIPO 0 = Primary roads
TIPO 1 = Secondary Roads
TIPO 2 = Tertiary roads
```

So the equation should be really simple: **Primary Roads/(Total Roads)**

In that Way, I made this Field Evaluator

```
 The value is: C
```

My script is:

```
Dim A

If [TIPO] = 0 Then

 A = [SHAPE_Length]

elseif [TIPO] = 1 Then

 A = [SHAPE_Length]

elseif [TIPO] = 2 Then

 A = [SHAPE_Length]

end if

Dim B

If [TIPO] = 0 Then

 B = [SHAPE_Length]

elseif [TIPO] = 1 Then

 B = 0

elseif [TIPO] = 2 Then

 B = 0

end if

Dim C

C = A / B

return
```

The value is: C
What happens is that even that the field Evaluator shows has okay(without errors), the when calculating the field, it shows 0 has an answer, and sometimes show an error messagem when I try to rebuild my network.

Comment: where's your return C? Your function does stuff but doesn't return a result. That isn't python, it's VBS.. which is out of favor with Esri but should still work. You've also got an extra end if that isn't matched by a starting if, it should be end function - but where's your function name?

Comment: Hello, indeed is VB script, I tried to do in VB because honestly dont know how to write in Python, it seems a lot more complicated. I just reviewed the script and edited it, what do you think about it?

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147141/vbscript-if-then-statement-field-calculator, vbscript is different to python in that there is no return and the variables go directly into the code block so that return is not needed. In the field calculator expression your field value is C. I also think it's not necessary to dim your variables in vbscript.